# Circuit building help

Tags: transistors

I'm a Noob at this and have a basic understanding of what relays do and how to use them.

I am putting an Auxiliary gas tank that feeds my factory tank through the filler neck on my truck. It has to have an electrical cut out to prevent over fill of the factory tank. I would like to have a set up where the voltage from the fuel sender wire (connected to a variable resistor on the factory tank float mech) isolates and activates a manual switch circuit in the cab that controls the Auxiliary fuel pump. I would like to have it to where at 1/2 factory tank the switch becomes hot and stays hot until full factory tank. At which point the switch would become isolated until it reaches 1/2 tank again. I have the switching part figured out using a latching relay driven from 2 more relays. (1 for 1/2 tank voltage and 1 for full tank voltage) The problem is the fuel sender voltage is very low 1.65v at 1/2 tank and 3.3v at full at around 25mA. I can't figure out how to trip the relays at a positive point. I thought about transistors using the low voltage and current to operate the base, but there is such a wide variety I can't figure out which one to use. I would like to use 12v relays so 12v at collector and emitter on the transistors I guess, unknown amperage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as well as any other ideas I haven't mentioned.  A diagram would be helpful as well. LOL

Comment: Yes, a diagram would be helpful.

Comment: why all the down votes?

Comment: Daniel, a picture, even a hand-sketched block diagram, is much easier to grasp than the word-picture you have painstakingly provided. I suspect that is why your question is getting so many downvotes.

Comment: Is this a convoluted way of asking how to introduce hysteresis into a level-sensing circuit?

Comment: Sparky electrical contacts and fuel vapors! Hee haw ...

Answer (score 2):

The question seems to revolve around sensing two voltage levels, 1.65V - the half full level, and 3.3V - the full level. 
The simplest solution I think is to use a dual comparator (LM319 or half an LM339 (quad)). www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/LM/LM319.pdf‎

[image]

Starting with the input signal from the sender unit. C1 (10uF) just smooths out a bit of noise from the sender unit wiper.

R1 and VR1 form a potential divider for the first comparator (A). The wiper voltage of VR1 is set to 1.65V (using a digital multimeter). {half full level}

R2 and VR2 form a potential divider for the second comparator (B). VR2 wiper voltage is set to 3.3V. {full level}

These two **reference voltages** are compared with the signal from the sender. If the sender voltage is LESS than the reference voltage the output of the comparator will be HIGH. As the comparators use OPEN COLLECTORS no current will be pulled through R3, R5 or R4, R6 which keeps the transistors (Q1,Q2 - PNP types) turned OFF.

When the sensor voltage rises ABOVE 1.65V (lower reference voltage)  the bottom comparator output (A) will go LOW and turn ON Q2  (the blue circuit). This will operate Relay RL1. This relay will remain turned ON as long as the tank is at least half full.

When the sensor voltage rises to 3.3V (or more) the second comparator (B) out will switch LOW and turn on Q1 (red circuit). This will operate relay RL2.

D1 and D2 prevent damage to the transistors due to back emf when the relays are turned OFF. Q1 and Q2 are PNP types 2N2907 or equivalent.

The timing diagram is shown below the circuit diagram.

Comment: Jim, your datasheet link for LM319 comes up as "*Unfortunately the page you requested has moved or is no longer available*" for me. Could you perhaps incorporate working datasheet links for the parts you mention?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh No problem Anindo. I did check the link just before I posted but it doesn't hurt to put up the pinouts as well just in case the link dies.

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason you don't want to just buy an off the shelf dual tank controller? It will take care of maintaining the right levels and display both from the cab and everything is already worked out properly.

If you don't want to do that, the correct way to do this is with a voltage comparator. By using two comparators they can be configured so it one will go active below 1.65V to drive the relay and the other will be active above 3.3V to drive the other one. The [LTC1440](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC1440) comparator has 40mA drive, which is enough for most smaller relays.